# How to silently drop a request in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat

From within an `HttpServlet` is it possible to drop a request and not return any http response?

For any given request an `HttpServlet` is provided an `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` objects.  Is there anything we can do to cause the connection dropped and no response sent?  I looked through the `HttpServletResponse` javadoc and I do not see anything in there that suggests dropping a request without sending anything.

thanks

Comment: Maybe 'if (condition) {return;}'?

Comment: That returns an empty response, but it is in fact a response.  It might even be a 200 OK if i'm not mistaken.  What I am looking for is a way to ignore the request.  I have to process the request first before I decide to ignore it, so I can't catch it further upstream by a separate process.

Comment: I doubt it since the request methods are void and provide you with an `HttpServletResponse` object. Perhaps by throwing an unchecked exception, but even then your web.xml should say which resource to redirect to – which will result in a response.

Comment: @JoseMartinez: what do you mean by *I have to process the request before I decide to ignore it*? Why would you ignore a request and what effect should it have on the client that is expecting a response?

Comment: There are two reasons I came up that may benefit from this.  One is security and the other is to quiet noisy clients that still have requests pending.  We check the cache to see if the pending request is done.  If we send back an error they respond right away again, versus backing off.  By not responding the client timesout versus spamming us.  This is a short term solution till the client's code can be fixed.

Comment: Why don't you 'park' their new request instead, and wait for the pending ones to finish before responding?

Comment: @okiharaherbst I would love to do that.  The problem is that it holds up a thread, on top of the first thread that is still processing the orignal request.  And second, if the client timesout I cannot tell from within the servlet and possibly leading to now a third thread being taken up.

Comment: Ok, you seem to be dealing with very particular clients actually. Unfortunately, I think that filters also send a response. How about a redirect instead?

Comment: @okiharaherbst thanks for the suggestion.  I'll look into that, sounds like a good idea.

Comment: Or perhaps a code 423 (resource locked).

Answer (score 1):

No. There will always be a response of some form, even if it is a very short one.

Strictly you could prevent a response by killing the Tomcat process but that is a rather excessive approach.